# how can insert admin user fields in database when install script php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

i start write a script with php , for installation stage i face to a problem.

when i install sql table with php code and after that "in same code page"  i want insert admin_user information to user table , without any error user information not inserted in database but when i install Manually database table and after that run same code for insert admin_user information inserted run good and information inserted in database.

My Query Run PDO Method :

```
  // Execute query
    public function Tbmedia_runquery($query_body = "" ,  $parameter_array ="" ){
        $query = $query_body;
        $stmt = $this->Tbmedia_connection->prepare($query);

                if(is_array($parameter_array)){
                    // declare bind_param variable
                    foreach ($parameter_array as $key => &$value) {
                        $stmt->bindParam(":$key",$value);
                        //':$key'
                    }
                }

         $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->closeCursor();
               return $stmt;

    }
```

And this is My Create Database Table Function :

```
//Create DB Table
    function Tbmedia_dbcreator($db_con){
    $dir_sql  = __DIR__."/../../install/tbmedia.sql";
        if(!file_exists($dir_sql) or is_writable($dir_sql)){
            $line_array  = file($dir_sql);
            $query_line = "";
            $query = "";
            foreach ($line_array as $value) {
                            if(substr($value,0,2) == "--")
                                continue;
                      $query_line .=$value;
                        if (substr(trim($value),-1,1) == ";"){
                            try{
                                $query = $db_con->Tbmedia_runquery($query_line);
                                $query_line = "";
                            }catch (Exception $e){
                                    $file_name = basename($e->getFile());
                                    $file_line = $e->getLine();
                                Tbmedia_die();
                            }

                        }
                }
        }else{
           Tbmedia_die();
        }
    }
```

And this is simple insert sql for insert user user information after run function Tbmedia_dbcreator() :

```
$db_con->Tbmedia_runquery('INSERT INTO `tbmedia`.`tbmedia_user` (`user_name`,`user_state`) VALUE ("FARAMARz",1)');
```

Why this is happening ? can't create table and insert data to it in one page code ?

Comment: Please, can you post a minimal snippet of your SQL code? [ask]

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.